# Get keys of a document in MongoDB Document

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Is there any way to get the list of keys of a particular document in MongoDB other than iterate through the document?

i.e I want to get the keys for the document returned by

```
db.users.find({username:'xyz@abc.com})
```

Are there any inline commands.If not,can anybody give an idea on how to do?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26063468/288875

Answer (score 5):

```
Object.keys(db.users.findOne({username:'xyz@abc.com'}))
```

will return a list of all the keys of a particular document.

Answer (score 3):

I know I am a little bit late to the party here, but you can do this in the mongo shell by typing:

```
var entry = db["users"].findOne({username:'xyz@abc.com});
for (var key in entry) { print(key); }
```

The important piece is `findOne`, this way you grab the fields of the first document rather than a list of the matching documents. Then you can simply loop through and print the keys.

Comment: +1 for noting that the important piece is the `fineOne`. Using just `find` will return a lot of stuff you aren't really interested in.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such command. You have to fetch the document and process it in the app.